# Marketing Cloud Einstein 'Track Cart' Tag not inserting into: PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

My Track Cart tag is giving 200 status code en underneath payload in Network

```
payload: {"cart":[
{"item":"TEES","quantity":"1","price":"24.95","item_type":"product","name":"Tee 1","unique_id":"202262"} "item":"SWEATERS","quantity":"1","price":"34.95","item_type":"product","name":"Sweater 2","unique_id":"205458"}],"url":"https://test.nl/winkelmand/","user_info":{"email":"test@email.nl"}}
```

But it does not insert a record into the Einstein DE. What is wrong with the syntax of the payload? / Is SetUserInfo neccesary for the Track Cart Tag?

In the Personalization Builder Status Console it says:
Track Cart Activity Collected Today:    189, but not visible in the DE.
Kind regards,
Rob

Comment: How do you proof that its not there? Have you looked inside the dataextension in marketing cloud `PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS` `PI_ABANDONED_CART_EVENT` because if you did... they are always empty...  . how long did you set your session?

Comment: Both PI_ABANDONED_CART_EVENT PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS DE are empty, the GTM tags are live since yesterday and currently there is one IGO_PROFILES of myself available in the DE IGO_PROFILES. With this Profile im trying to test the other tags. What do you mean by session?

Comment: Your session length determines when a contact counts as "Abandoned Cart"

Comment: The GTM trigger is on pageview of the shopping cart. Are you referring to the trigger of the Tag or a setting I dont know about? please explain.

Comment: Please go to web and mobile analytics and look if you have these numbers aswell and check out your number of abandoned carts. Also go to web recommendations - implementations, bottom left ADVANCED settings - there you can see your session length

Comment: 99 Abandoned Carts today, but the Session Length is on 1 hour default. Does this explain why there are no records?

Comment: The dataextension WILL NEVER show any records. just like i said in my first comment ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answers! why do they exist then? I did not understand that the first time:) I am setting them up for Email reccomandations. IGO_VIEWS, IGO_PROFILES, IGO_PRODUCTS, IGO_PRODUCTATTRIBS are filled at the moment, will IGO_PURCHASES be filled by  _etmc.push(["trackConversion"  and they have a profile?

Comment: `IGO_PURCHASES` will have a lot of data records that are connected with the user_id set in `IGO_PROFILES`. To see a customer profile you can visit personalization builder -> web recommendations -> admin -> contacts -> enter an "email" value and klick go or enter... :D

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS Johannes has stated, this DE is not populated

[PI Data Extensions for Personalization Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000319381&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

> The following Data Extensions are included as part of the provisioning process. However, these Data Extensions are reserved for future use, so these Data Extensions should not be expected to get populated with data.
>
> PI_SESSIONS
>
> PI_SESSION_ENDS
>
> PI_ABANDONED_CART_ITEMS
>
> PI_ABANDONED_CART_EVENT